# Word Usage: But... None/Nevertheless vs None/Nevertheless itself?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I'm in doubt because I don't know what's the difference between "But...None/nevertheless" and just the Nonetheless/Nevertheless itself.

Example:

> He is busy.Nevertheless, he still calls me.

That is an example I've found on the internet. But what would the difference be if I used the expression "but nevertheless" instead?

> He's always busy. *But nevertheless*, he still calls me.

What are the difference between these 2 sentences? And, what are the differences between "but never/nonetheless" and just those adverbs itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some* people will claim that [***nonetheless*** is used when talking about **an amount** of something](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72143/2637) - but I side with those (highly knowledgeable, imho) commenters disagreeing with that assertion on ELU.

Putting that aside, ***but nevertheless*** is effectively *tautologous*, in that either word could be discarded without affecting the meaning at all (but nevertheless, that particular two-word collocation is perfectly common and "natural").

In short, it makes no real difference whether you use ***nonetheless*** or ***nevertheless***, OR whether you precede your chosen form by ***but***. In the context of OP's example, ***all*** such permutations are precisely equivalent to ***Although*** he's busy, he still calls.

It's probably worth explicitly pointing that although the three-word form ***none the less*** does exist, and has a somewhat different sense<sup>1</sup> to the single-word form, there's no equivalent three-word form ***never the less*** in "normal" English. Also note that ***nonetheless*** has [only recently risen to prominence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nevertheless%2Cnonetheless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnevertheless%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonetheless%3B%2Cc0) (and it's still much less common than ***nevertheless***, so my advice would be to stick with the latter).

---

<sup>1</sup> From [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/difference-between-nevertheless-and-nonetheless/72143#comment140389_72143) under the ELU question linked to by my first sentence above...

> Jim (citing example attempting to prove that ***nevertheless*** and ***nonetheless*** are different)
>    *Julius II loved him nonetheless for it...* means Julius didn't love him any less because of it
>
> Colin Fine (shooting that example down)
>    Ah. I see the problem. That is not the word ***nonetheless***: it is the phrase ***none the less***. To see the difference, consider *Julius did not love him **any the less***. There is no word ***anytheless***.

Comment: Does it matter what any given user on this site claims regarding usage? What matters is _actual usage_. If people use a word to mean something, then it means that something. I couldn't care less how "Jim" personally feels about the subject.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica: Of course it matters! Not wishing to slag anyone off, it seems likely to me that many of the people proposing / upvoting that false distinction don't normally use *either* form themselves. They just see what looks at first glance to be a *convincing rationale*, so they go along with it. I think you'd find few if any instances of *published* authors in Google Books making any such distinction. It's on a par with thinking you can't end a sentence with a preposition, or supposing that only one of ***ripe / rife** with opportunity* is "correct".

Comment: (But I quite agree that *as a general principle*, Humpty Dumpty was quite right when he said *Words mean what I want them to mean*. If a grammarian disagrees with what people *actually* say/mean, it's pretty much axiomatic that they're right and he's wrong.)

Comment: You are using a lot of words to not say very much. Like I said, one person's opinion doesn't matter. _Usage_ matters.

Comment: I think I've made my position abundantly clear. You, on the other hand, haven't even explicitly stated whether *you personally* accept that supposed distinction (and more crucially, whether you've ***always*** recognised it, or just read and been convinced by someone else's "logical deconstruction" as a result of this question being posed).

Comment: You sure do love adverbs, eh? I have no idea what you're talking about. Supposed distinction of what? All I'm saying is "appeal to authority" doesn't mean anything when talking about the English language. There is no authority. If people use a word to mean something, then it means that something. If you don't agree with that, cool. It's reality, though. I don't know what you're trying to argue.